# Cannot return the content from a nested array in React JS

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am trying to display the data I fetched from an API which is a nested array. The json file looks like this for one pool and the devices inside that pool:

```
[
   {
    "id": "staging",
    "pool": "some name",
    "status": "FAILED",
    "deviceMonitoringEntries": [
      {
        "deviceDescriptor":{
          
          "id": "Apple_TV_HD1",
         }
     ]
   }
]
```

I want to display the `id` of the pool first and then display the devices assigned to the pool by displaying the `id` in `deviceDescriptor`.

My code is like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
function Pool(){
    
    const url = 'http://localhost:8043/pools'
    const [pool, setPool] = useState(null)

    let content = null

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response =>{
                setPool(response.data)
        })
    }, [url])
    
    
    if(pool){
        console.log("in if pool")
        console.log(pool)
        return (
            content=
            <>
                {pool.map((id) => {
                    
                    <h3 key = {id}>{id}</h3>
                    return (
                        <>{pool.map(({ deviceMonitoringEntries}) => (
                            deviceMonitoringEntries.map((deviceDescriptor) => (
                                <p key = {deviceDescriptor.id}>  {deviceDescriptor.id}</p>
                                ))
                        ))}</>
                        
                    );
                })}        
            </>
        )
    }

    
    return(
        <div>
            {content}
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Pool
```

However, the header `<h3 key = {id}>{id}</h3>` never prints. I can display the header and paragraph separately but it does not work together. I am very new to React and I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Because it is outside of the nested `return`.

Comment: but I cannot add it inside, it complains about that ',' is expected @morganney

Answer (score 0):

As per React documentation

> React components implement a render() method that takes input data and returns what to display.
>
> In the functional component, you directly add a return statement at the end.

You cannot assign variables like this in your code.

```
return (
   content=
<>
...

</>
```

You got the response and you stored that value in a state variable. Use the variable and render your content in the final return statement.

```
{
  pool.map((p) => (
    <>
      <h3 key={p.id}>{p.id}</h3>
      {p.deviceMonitoringEntries.map((device) => (
        <p key={device?.deviceDescriptor?.id}>{device.deviceDescriptor?.id}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  ));
}
```

You can try like that in your code and I am attaching a sandbox for reference here.
[image: Edit distracted-cookies-r8jz9w]